# iterate through array and log selected entries to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array called customers, each customer has a name, id, account number, address and account information:

```
var customers = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "id": 1205,
        "accountNumber": 187456,
        "address": {
            "houseNumber": 12,
            "streetName": "made up street",
            "postCode": "WE1 234",
            "area": "Birmingham"
        },
        "hasCurrentAccount": true,
        "hasLoan": false,
        "hasMortgage": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "id": 1304,
        "accountNumber": 123456,
        "address": {
            "houseNumber": 420,
            "streetName": "The Street",
            "postCode": "DE3 456",
            "area": "Wolverhampton"
        },
        "hasCurrentAccount": false,
        "hasLoan": true,
        "hasMortgage": false
    }
];
```

for now I'm trying to iterate through this array retrieve the name and id and print it to the console:

```
var info = customers;
for (var i in info)
{
   var id = info.id;
   var name = info.name;
   console.log('Here are your current customers' + id + ' ' + name);
}
```

but I just get

```
Here are your current customers undefined undefined
```

I've tried different methods and I just can't seem to get it working. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no JSON in your example. Only a (JavaScript) array of objects. Hint: You are using `for (var i in info)` but are never doing anything with `i`.

Comment: I should've noted that I was originally using JSON but I changed to an array! 
I'll edit it now.

Comment: @nicovank: That would also result in `undefined`.

Comment: @nicovank that comes up as defined in the console as well.

Comment: `var i of info` or `info[i].id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Array.forEach` function to iterate through the array.
It runs a function on each item, which is where you can log values from the item to the console.

Example:

```js
var customers = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "id": 1205,
        "accountNumber": 187456,
        "address": {
            "houseNumber": 12,
            "streetName": "made up street",
            "postCode": "WE1 234",
            "area": "Birmingham"
        },
        "hasCurrentAccount": true,
        "hasLoan": false,
        "hasMortgage": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "id": 1304,
        "accountNumber": 123456,
        "address": {
            "houseNumber": 420,
            "streetName": "The Street",
            "postCode": "DE3 456",
            "area": "Wolverhampton"
        },
        "hasCurrentAccount": false,
        "hasLoan": true,
        "hasMortgage": false
    }
];

customers.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log('Here are your current customers', item.id, item.name);
})
```

Comment: Your post will be much more useful to others if you explain what the problem is and how your solution solves it. Code only answers are usually considered low quality.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, edited

Comment: @Giladd This works like a charm! 

So I could do this for each item in the array?

Comment: Yeah, full docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
for (a in customers){
console.log('Here are your current customers' + a + ' ' + customers[a].name);
}
```

Comment: Your post will be much more useful to others if you explain what the problem is and how your solution solves it. *"Try this"* is just an unnecessary statement.